# Is it possible to buy all the Supply Shack items on Survivor difficulty?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

Since money is shorter in Survivor mode, is it actually feasible to purchase all items in the shop, or would I need a playthrough on a lower difficulty to do this?